# Options for better performance instead of using for loops | Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, performance, data-science

I have 2 tables from 2 different systems. The identifiers (column ID) of these systems are not equal. I have a mapping file which says, which ID from system 1 matches to which ID from system 2.

These three files are given as xlsx files and are imported into data frames (pandas). The task is to write something from one cell in system 1 to the correct cell in system 2. I have to implement this task in Python. Maybe you can help me!

The following code is simplified to the core of my question.. the **performance**! I have looked for other solutions (`np.where` & binary search), but my skills are to weak and I`m getting more and more exhausted. Maybe you can help me!

```py
# Iterate through every row in df_system1
for a in tqdm(df_system1.index, total=len(df_system1)):
    # Search for the matching key in the df_keyTable
    for b in df_keyTable.index: 
        # Search for the ID in df_system2, which matches to the key and do...
        for c in df_system1:
```

Each of these tables cointains more than 25000 rows, which is the reason why I can't implement the  task with for loops.

Comment: Look into `merge`: `df_keyTable.merge(df_system1, on=...).merge(df_system2, on=...)`

Comment: `merge` is the better way to solve this. Please include the key names in `df_system1`, `df_system2`  and `df_keyTable` if you want better help